# Manjaro boots to white screen after uninstalling ttf-google-fonts-git

Tags: kde, fonts, manjaro, aur

I'm pretty new to Linux. I've got Manjaro 16.06.1 with KDE Plasma running on virtual machine. I was working great until I **uninstalled** package named ttf-google-fonts-git via octopi (it also uninstalled by default many dependencies).

After rebooting, system freezes on a blank page (right after displaying Manjaro loading screen - the one with green dots under logo).

What can I do about it? Can I run live cd and try to reinstall without loosing data and configuration?

Comment: Easiest way is to boot with a live cd, chroot the existing platform and reinstall the missing packages, e.g. https://mzanfardino.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/repairing-broken-arch-linux/

Comment: Thx for the replay, but this manual doesn't help me. I don't have such file: /dev/mapper/vg-lv_root. I've only got `control` file in this directory, and when I try to do this anyway I get: `mount: /dev/mapper/control is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount:  /dev/mapper/control is not a block device`

Comment: I managed to chroot by `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt` and `sudo chroot /mnt` but when I try to reinstall the package I get: `grep: /dev/fd/63 No such file or directory` and `/dev/null:  Permission denied` and also `no tty present and no askpass program specified`

Comment: Yeah, that link was just an example. Best to search for chroot, archlinux, rescue, pacman etc. some more, information is out there, I cannot answer properly, just wanted to give you some feedback. It's a common enough problem and solvable. Maybe check out the #archlinux channel on Freenode to get some live assistance and/or ask on the Archlinux forum